# "whatis" returns 0 for missing commands

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, unix

On macOS 10.14, using `whatis` on a command that is not installed prints `'command': nothing appropriate` as is expected.  But returns 0 instead of an error code, which I believe is expected behavior.  It is also not consistent with `man`, which returns 1 after no results.  Additionally, `whatis` prints to stdout, while `man` prints to stderr.

This is different than Linux, which returns an error code, and prints to stderr.

macOS:

```
$ whatis abc; echo $?
abc: nothing appropriate
0

$ man abc; echo $?
No manual entry for abc
1

$ whatis abc 2>/dev/null
abc: nothing appropriate

$ man abc 2>/dev/null
```

Linux (Ubuntu):

```
$ whatis abc; echo $?
abc: nothing appropriate.
16

$ man abc; echo $?
No manual entry for abc
16

$ whatis abc 2>/dev/null

$ man abc 2>/dev/null
```

I believe `whatis` should not return 0 when it fails to find a description of the command, and should have behavior consistent with `man`

Note: I noticed this because I'm writing a program that relies on this functionality

Edit: `apropos` has the same behavior as `whatis`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS `whatis` is just a shell script.

```
$ type whatis
whatis is hashed (/usr/bin/whatis)
$ file /usr/bin/whatis
/usr/bin/whatis: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text
```

If you look inside, the relevant part reads

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
    found=0
    for d in /var/cache/man $manpath /usr/lib
    do
        if [ -f $d/whatis ]
        then
            if grep -"$grepopt1" "$grepopt2""$1" $d/whatis
            then
                found=1
            fi
        fi
    done

    if [ $found = 0 ]
    then
        echo "$1: nothing appropriate"
    fi

    shift
done | eval ${PAGER:-more -E}
```

So if no entries are found (the `if [ $found = 0 ]` part), the message is displayed without setting any exit code. Actually the script only exits with status 1 if wrong arguments have been passed.

The most recent update notice relates to `2003-08-01` as the date of update, so it seems to be rather old anyway. Whether the behaviour is a feature or a bug is open for discussion.

---

In case you are wondering about `apropos` showing the same behaviour: `apropos` and `whatis` are basically the same script.

```
$ ll /usr/bin/{apropos,whatis}
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1808 Aug 18 00:18 /usr/bin/apropos*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1806 Aug 18 00:18 /usr/bin/whatis*
$ diff /usr/bin/{apropos,whatis}
26,27c26,27
< grepopt1=$aproposgrepopt1
< grepopt2=$aproposgrepopt2
---
> grepopt1=$whatisgrepopt1
> grepopt2=$whatisgrepopt2
```

Comment: Thank you.  In Ubuntu `whatis` is compiled, so we cannot do a similar analysis on it.  I would argue that macOS' behavior is inferior to Linux's.  It seems clear that trying to get information about a command that does not exist should return an error.  `which abc` returns 1, `man abc` returns 1, etc.  While `whatis` is not part of POSIX, I cannot say Apple's implementation is 'wrong', but I cannot see *advantages* to returning 0 and outputting to stdout.

Comment: @MaxCoplan Probably easier to roll your own version if needed.

Comment: That's what I've just done.  Thank you!  Your answer let me simply copy `whatis` to my local bin and edit it there.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349920/modifying-whatis-to-return-error-code-for-missing-commands