# Modifying `whatis` to return error code for missing commands

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, unix

Followup to ["whatis" returns 0 for missing commands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348954/whatis-returns-0-for-missing-commands), I am trying to modify `/usr/bin/whatis` to return a non-zero exit code after an inappropriate command has been entered.  My approach to doing this is to add a return variable in the following segment, and return that variable after the end of the loop

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
    found=0
    for d in /var/cache/man $manpath /usr/lib
    do
        if [ -f $d/whatis ]
        then
            if grep -"$grepopt1" "$grepopt2""$1" $d/whatis
            then
                found=1
            fi
        fi
    done

    if [ $found = 0 ]
    then
        echo "$1: nothing appropriate"
        **code=1**
    fi

    shift
done | eval ${PAGER:-more -E}
**return $code**
```

However, since the `while` loop is piped into `eval`, it is run in a subshell so `code` will not be assigned outside the `while` loop.  I have tried [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered) [different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/modify-global-variable-in-while-loop) [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667509/shell-variables-set-inside-while-loop-not-visible-outside-of-it), however, these are all about piping a value INTO the `while` loop, not piping a value out of the `while` loop.

A workaround I found is simply removing the entire `eval` statement, but I would like a method that preserves the original extensibility of `whatis`

Answer (score 1):

`PIPESTATUS` is an array. Since you only need `$[PIPESTATUS[0]}`, the subscript can be omitted.

```
(
    code=0
    while [ "$1" != "" ]
    do
        found=0
        for d in /var/cache/man $manpath /usr/lib
        do
            if [ -f $d/whatis ]
            then
                if grep -"$grepopt1" "$grepopt2""$1" $d/whatis
                then
                    found=1
                fi
            fi
        done

        if [ $found = 0 ]
        then
            echo "$1: nothing appropriate"
            code=1
        fi

        shift
    done
    exit $code
) | eval ${PAGER:-more -E}
return $PIPESTATUS
```

From `man bash`:

```
   PIPESTATUS
          An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list  of  exit
          status  values  from the processes in the most-recently-executed
          foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).
```

Comment: Trying to return `$PIPESTATUS` gives the following error
`$ whatis hi
hi: nothing appropriate
/usr/local/bin/whatis: line 92: return: can only \`return' from a function or sourced script`
However, doing `exit $PIPESTATUS` instead of `return` works fine

Comment: I never ran your script. Nor did I attempt to correct any errors you may have made. I did not think you ask me to. You asked how to read the value of the variable `code` after the pipe completes, which is what I put in my answer. If you want someone to write your script, ask a new question. Also, if you desire, feel free to edit both your question and/or my answer. Or, post your own answer.